# SQL To Show Something After Certain Amount of Days

Tags: php, mysql, date

***EDIT***

---

i have taken some of Ashley Banks code and inserted into mine without any success. I am not getting any errors but I am also not getting any data to show up. my code is as follows::

```
    <?php
$id = $_GET['meeting_id'];
$from = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $row['date_update'] . '-7 days' ) ); 

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Meetings LEFT JOIN Minutes ON Meetings.meeting_id = Minutes.meeting_id 

INNER JOIN Rooms ON Meetings.meeting_id = Rooms.meeting_id 

WHERE  Rooms.date >= "' . $from . '" AND Rooms.date <= NOW() AND Minutes.approval = "approved" AND Meetings.meeting_id = "$id"')

or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
       echo '<h3>There Arent Any Minutes For This Meeting Yet</h3>';
    } else {

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><br/>" .'Title: '. $info['title']." </td>";
        echo "<td><br/><br/>" .'Subject: '. $info['subject']. "</td>";
        echo "<td><br/><br/>" .'Next Subject: '. $info['next_subject']."</td>";

        echo '<br/><br/><a href="attendees.php?meeting_id=' . $info['meeting_id'] . '" target="_blank">Attendees</a>';
        echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;<a href="apologies.php?meeting_id=' . $info['meeting_id'] . '" target="_blank">Apologies</a>';



        }
    }
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";


?>
```

Remember, these my my tables and fields:

Meetings: meeting_id, title, chairman, secretary, tof, occurances, action

Rooms: room_id, room, date (this is in a varchar field, i know its not in the right format but it was made like that), time, meeting_id.

Minutes: minute_id, subject, next_subject, approval, meeting_id

it is not showing any data. it just echo'ing my message which is 'There arent any minutes for this meeting yet'

MY DATE FIELD IN THE ROOMS TABLE IS NOW OF A DATE FORMAT AND NOT A VARCHAR ANYMORE

Answer (score 0):

This might help, example of something I was working on last week:

```
$from = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $row['date_update'] . '-15 days' ) ); 

$query = $this->db->get ( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE table_date >= "' . $from . '" AND table_date <= NOW() ORDER BY table_date DESC' );
```

This is just a brief example, but it will find results between two dates, setting $from to be from 15 days of the date I have provided ( in that case an output from my database ), so you could use it for anything.

Comment: will this work even though my date field in my database is not of a date format but in a varchar format?

Comment: take your date field and wrap in date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $yourfield ) )

Comment: PLEASE CHECK MY 1st POST...IT HAS NOW BEEN EDITED

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to convert your varchar "date" to a real date, and then compare it to curdate() - 7 days.
See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Ending up with something like this:

```
AND str_to_date(Meetings.date,'%d,%m,%Y') > date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day)
```

Comment: PLEASE CHECK MY 1st POST...IT HAS NOW BEEN EDITED

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Minutes m, Rooms r
WHERE
    m.meeting_id = r.meeting_id AND
    r.date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

You have to change this according to your date field. This is if date was a `DATETIME` field, if it is a `VARCHAR` containing a timestamp, you could use something like

```
CAST(r.date AS UNSIGNED) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-7*24*60*60
```

If your `VARCHAR` contains the date as a string (not a good idea anyway), use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` on the date field before.

You have to do some casting back and forth but with some trying I'm sure you'll get the hang of it

Comment: PLEASE CHECK MY 1st POST...IT HAS NOW BEEN EDITED